# Setting Editor from HTML

Tags: lexicaljs

I'm looking to replace an existing HTML editor with Lexical. I'm using the code from the web site to convert HTML to nodes as the starting point.

https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/serialization

The data is being converted and the nodes are being generated.

However, get the following error when inserting the nodes?

Error: insertNode: topLevelElement is root node
at RangeSelection.insertNodes (c:\Projects\ActivateV8\Activate.React.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\lexical\Lexical.dev.js:4002:1)

```
function SetDataPlugin ({model}) {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!model) return;
      
    editor.update(() => {
      // In the browser you can use the native DOMParser API to parse the HTML string.
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const dom = parser.parseFromString(model, "text/html");
      
      // Once you have the DOM instance it's easy to generate LexicalNodes.
      const nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(editor, dom);
      
      // Select the root
      $getRoot().select();
    
      // Insert them at a selection.
      const selection = $getSelection();
      selection.insertNodes(nodes);
    });
  }, [editor,model]);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working with the following code

```
  editor.update(() => {
      // In the browser you can use the native DOMParser API to parse the HTML string.
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const dom = parser.parseFromString(model, "text/html");
      
      // Once you have the DOM instance it's easy to generate LexicalNodes.
      const nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(editor, dom);
      
      // Select the root
      const root = $getRoot()

      const paragraphNode = $createParagraphNode();

      nodes.forEach((n)=> paragraphNode.append(n))
     
      root.append(paragraphNode);
    });
```

Comment: this solution helps me fix a bug with tables (when empty parapgraph divides table between random rows). 10Q so much

Comment: added `root.getFirstDescendant()?.remove()` to remove the blank node added on render

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, thanks! One short addition would be, that you don't have to use the `paragraphNode`, because it can yield invalid html code (eg p > h1). I'd recommend adding the nodes directly to the root:
`nodes.forEach((node) => root.append(node))`

Comment: If you don't want all nodes to be a paragraph mode just insert nodes using `$insertNodes` ref: https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/serialization

Answer (score 2):

This is the only working html to JSON Lexical script I found. Lexical documentation presents the wrong examples that do not work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-paper-op41gv?file=/src/Editor.js

```
const editorConfig = {
  // The editor theme
  theme: ExampleTheme,
  // Handling of errors during update
  onError(error) {
    throw error;
  },
  // Any custom nodes go here
  nodes: [
    HeadingNode,
    ListNode,
    ListItemNode,
    QuoteNode,
    CodeNode,
    CodeHighlightNode,
    TableNode,
    TableCellNode,
    TableRowNode,
    AutoLinkNode,
    LinkNode
  ]
};

function LoadHtmlPlugin() {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();

  editor.update(() => {
    let nodes = [];
    const html = `
    <ul class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__ul"><li value="1" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__listItem PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">Visit the </span><a href="https://lexical.dev/" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__link PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">Lexical website</span></a><span data-lexical-text="true"> for documentation and more information.</span></li><li value="2" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__listItem PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">Check out the code on our </span><a href="https://github.com/facebook/lexical" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__link PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">GitHub repository</span></a><span data-lexical-text="true">.</span></li><li value="3" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__listItem PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">Playground code can be found </span><a href="https://github.com/facebook/lexical/tree/main/packages/lexical-playground" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__link PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">here</span></a><span data-lexical-text="true">.</span></li><li value="4" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__listItem PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">Join our </span><a href="https://discord.com/invite/KmG4wQnnD9" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__link PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">Discord Server</span></a><span data-lexical-text="true"> and chat with the team.</span></li><li value="5" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__listItem PlaygroundEditorTheme__nestedListItem"><ul class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__ul"><li value="1" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__listItem PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">Item 1</span></li><li value="2" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__listItem PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">Item 2</span></li><li value="3" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__listItem PlaygroundEditorTheme__nestedListItem"><ul class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__ul"><li value="1" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__listItem PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">Item 3</span></li><li value="2" class="PlaygroundEditorTheme__listItem PlaygroundEditorTheme__ltr" dir="ltr"><span data-lexical-text="true">Item 4</span></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
    `;

    // Parse html
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const dom = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(editor, dom);

    // Set content
    const root = $getRoot();
    root.clear();
    root.append(...nodes);
  });

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add types. Worked ;)

```
const selection = $getSelection() as RangeSelection;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.update(() => {
    // In the browser you can use the native DOMParser API to parse the HTML string.
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const dom = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

    // Once you have the DOM instance it's easy to generate LexicalNodes.
    const nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(editor, dom);

    // Select the root
    $getRoot().select();

    // Insert them at a selection.
    const selection = $getSelection();

    if ($isRangeSelection(selection)) {
      if ($isRootNode(selection.anchor.getNode())) {
        selection.insertParagraph();
      }
      selection.insertNodes(nodes);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It didn't work for me but did give me a hint on how to get it working. Example in the next Answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { $createLineBreakNode, $createRangeSelection, $getRoot, LineBreakNode } from 'lexical';
import { $insertGeneratedNodes } from '@lexical/clipboard';
import { $generateNodesFromDOM } from '@lexical/html';

...

editor.update(() => {
  // In the browser you can use the native DOMParser API to parse the HTML string.
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const dom = parser.parseFromString(draftHtml, 'text/html');
  // Once you have the DOM instance it's easy to generate LexicalNodes.
  const nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(editor, dom);
  // clear content
  $getRoot().clear();
  // add nodes
  $insertGeneratedNodes(
    editor,
    nodes
      .map((node, idx) =>
        idx > 0 && !(nodes[idx - 1] instanceof LineBreakNode)
          ? // any custom format
            [$createLineBreakNode(), node, $createLineBreakNode()]
          : [node],
      )
      .flat(),
    $createRangeSelection(),
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**